# Manual VS Automatic Transmissions Suitability

Tags: automatic-transmission, manual-transmission, wear

On weekends I do deliveries. I make over 150+ stops, short distances apart and engage gears 1/2/3 and reverse during every stop.

Which transmission setup would be best suited for such a scenario? Currently I drive a manual.

I wonder whether an automatic would be better suited, more efficient and lead to less wear on the components? Saying that as doing that for 6 hours non-stop it's likely gear shifting/clutch engagement wouldn't be as accurate throughout even for a seasoned driver. I'm not concerned about comfort as aware an automatic is much easier but more so on component wear/durability.

Comment: The received wisdom is that an automatic gearbox is not as durable as a manual. I have owned two vehicles with DSG (simply hated the 1950's designs) and both did give some probems. But of my many manual cars, only one suffered a gearbox fault (a Hillman Imp, where a small part that cost 1 penny had a habit of breaking and mashing the gear teeth). Of course, a manual gearbox's clutch plates and release bearing need periodical replacement, but are relatively inexpensive. But what I can say, is that for town driving, an automatic is the superior experience.

Comment: ...as long as you remember to put it in neutral or park or switch off before you get out of the car :) Sadly, the annoying nanny systems don't reckon with that, although they might turn off the seat heater.